# Are there any special requirements for resolving namespaces for Sealed Classes?

Tags: c#

I have created a Sealed Class called Transactions with some static methods and compiled it successfully. I then created a Test Project to test the functionality of all my methods and added a reference to the dll file of the Sealed Class.

When I begin typing the Namespace of the class in my Test Project, intellisense resolves the reference and adds it.

I can even Type the Class Name and intellisense provides the complete list of public methods and properties for the Class, but when I attempt to compile the project I get the error "The type or namespace name 'Transactions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

When I double-click the error it points to the Namespace reference at the top of my code. If I remove the Namespace I get a question mark when I hover over my method call prompting to add the Namespace that I just removed. What the ???

So on one account it complains that it can't find the Namespace during compilation, and on the other if I remove the namespace it recognizes the dependency of the method and wants me to add it back. I am stuck literally between a rock and a hard place.

My only suspicion is the use of the Sealed Class that is causing the issue because if I create another class (not Sealed) and add the same method the issue goes away.

Thoughts or advice would be appreciated. This is the .NET 4.0 Framework

Comment: Are you sure that the project containing your sealed class compiles?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your projects properties if they both use the same "flavor" of framework (client profile/ full fledge, different versions of the framework). This is usually the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Cedric, I think I stumbled across the answer at the same time you provided the post so I am flagging your answer although I posted one as well.

Comment: Thanks ;o) As your answer is more complete, I return the favor to you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured the issue out. Turns out that my Test App automagically was set to use the .NET 4 Client Profile. I found this out when I noted one of the warnings that stated the reference to my Transactions dll could not be resolved because of a dependency on the System.Web.

When I attempted to add the Reference I could not locate it and saw that the results of available assemblies were filtered based on the .NET 4 Client Profile. After I changed the profile to match that of my assembly (.NET 4.0) then I was able to add the required reference to the System.Web assembly and my code compiled without issue.

Moral of this experience for me is not to take the warnings presented within the environment for granted because although most of the time they may be ignored, there are instances when they actually assist in resolving the errors as well.

Hopefully this post will help someone else but the Title for the question may be misleading since I was under false presumptions when I posted it.

Thanks